# link not appearing on hover using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, hover

I want to make a div visible when hovering another div. Now, I know this can be implemented using simply jquery but its not working. I am populating a list using javascript as given below :

```
function coachingLink(data, list) {
   list = list
    + '<div class="**coachingLinkDisplay**"><p class="coachingLink" align="left" style="color:#CD3700;">'
    + data.coachingName
    + '</p><br/>'
    + '<p class="title" style="color:black;font-size:14pt;">Subjects : '
    + subjects + '</p><br/><p class="content" align="left"></b>'
    + data.description + '</p></div></a><a href="batch.html?coachingId='
    + data.coachingId
    + '" class="**batchButton**"><b>View Batches</b></a>';

    return list;
}
```

Now what I want that when hovering over coachingLinkDisplay, batchButton should appear (whose display is none initially) . So I wrote the code :

```
$(document).ready(
   function() {
     $('.coachingLinkDisplay').hover(function() {
     $('.batchButton').css('display', 'block');
   }); 
});
```

But the code is not working. It seems as the list is being populated using JS, may be the above jquery snippet is failing as I have tried the snippet for normal div and is working properly. So, I tried to use css approach as I read in various blogs:

```
.coachingLinkDisplay:hover  + .batchButton{
   display:block;
}
```

But again no luck..is there any problem in above css code? Please help me out here...how to implement my requirement...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to delegate the hover function. This is because the event handler is only bound to elements available during document ready.

```
$(document).on('mouseover', '.coachingLinkDisplay', function(){
    $('.batchButton').css('display', 'block');
});
```

Replace `document` with the closest static parent element.

Comment: That worked...but I am not able to understand how...I mean what is the difference between your approach and mine..?

Comment: @vladhalmer The reason this works is because you are adding the elements dynamically to the DOM, meaning, they are not available at page load. Static event handlers will only bind to elements that are available when `$(document).ready()` fires. If the element doesn't exist, then you need a dynamic event handler, which is exactly what the `.on()` does when supplying a static element first, I.E. `$(document)`, then using  `.coachingLinkDisplay` as the element you wish to delegate dynamic events to.